# Postfix in C++ not behaving like I'd expect

Tags: c++, postfix-operator

I understand the basic differences between prefix/postfix notation for decrement/increment operators in C++.  However, there is something going on in the next example that stumps me.

The code I shared below prints the following.

5*4**3***4****2*****1

But I would have guessed it would print this.

5*4**4***3****2*****1

How is this happening?  Is something going on with pushing/popping to/from the stack?

```
int var = 5;
cout << var-- << '*'; //prints 5 and then decrements to 4.
cout << var << "**"; //The value of var (now 4) 
                     //is printed to the console.
//The next line prints 3***4****.
//I would have guessed it prints  4***3****.
cout << var-- << "***" << var-- << "****";  
//No matter what the above line prints, 
//the value of var after the above lines is 2, so...
cout << var-- << "*****" << var << endl; //...Print 2, decrement to 1 
                                         //and then 1 is finally printed.
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 10 laptop...Several of my students got the same result as me as well.  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: @krsju Take care with the warning messages: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22eda0ae6e1f21d9 and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: Warning messages: The first line of defense against logic errors. Ignore at your own risk.

Comment: ```g++-9.2 -Wall -pedantic test.cpp``` gives this warning: ```warning: operation on ‘var’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]``` with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the strange world of undefined behaviour. Calling an increment or decrement operator twice on the same variable, in the same statement, is undefined behaviour, so don't do it :)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int i = 1;
  // should this print 9, 10, or 12? Compilers will vary... 
  std::cout << (++i + ++i + ++i) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this one changed in C++17. [Here's cppreference's take on it.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Sequenced-before_rules_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29)

Comment: Whether it's ever allowed or not, it's never going to be readable (or maintainable) code imho.

Comment: That I'll agree with.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am just surprised because this example came from a brand new famous author's textbook. I would have thought the text would either warn about this issue or not asked students to predict output related to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this line:

```
cout << var-- << "***" << var-- << "****";
```

is undefined behaviour because you using post-decrement twice in a single statement.